# Python (falcon) transition is read only

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, falconframework

I'm running into a strange error -`psycopg2.errors.ReadOnlySqlTransaction: transaction is read-only` when i'm trying to read data from my redshift database from my python application. I'm not trying to modify the database so i'm not sure why this happens. I'm using a postgresql plugin (psycopg2) version 2.8.4. And python version 3.5 -I have lot of other queries that i'm running in the same approach and they work without a problem, so i'm a little confused what could be causing this.

Here is the query i'm running

```
SELECT
    stat_date,
    age,
    name,
    SUM(spent) as spent,
FROM (

    SELECT stat_date, age,name, spent
    FROM mview_a
    WHERE id in ('id1', 'id2')

UNION ALL

    SELECT stat_date, age,name, spent
    FROM mview_b
    WHERE id in ('id1', 'id2')

UNION ALL

    SELECT stat_date, age,name, spent
    FROM mview_c
    WHERE id in ('id1', 'id2')

UNION ALL

    SELECT stat_date, age,name, spent
    FROM view_d (combination of multiple mviews)
    WHERE id in ('id1', 'id2')

UNION ALL

    SELECT stat_date, age,name, spent
    FROM mview_e
    WHERE id in ('id1', 'id2')

)

GROUP BY 1;
```

And this is how i pass my query along with params

```
dw = self.get_conn(conn)
results = dw.fetch_all_query(query, params=params, **kwargs)
```

And the database calls fails on this line from psycopg2 package.

```
self.execute_query(q, dict_cursor=dict_cursor, params=params,
                   readonly=readonly, autocommit=autocommit, conn=False)
```

Comment: This has lot missing. Have no idea what `dw.fetch_all_query` is doing?  Or how that leads to `self.execute_query(...)`? Or what `q` actually is in `self.execute_query(q, ...)`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it just calls execute_query which is coming from psycopg2. The dw is just to specify what data source is being used.

Comment: There is no `execute_query` in psycopg2. And you still have not told us what `query` and `q` refer to. As long the information provided is incomplete the chances of an answer are slim.

Comment: My bad, i thought it was clear. The q is referring to the query, and query is the query i shared in the post. I didn't think this would have been related to low-level implementation of psycopg2 or the code. I have other code blocks that are using the exact same logic and working. So i was thinking the transition-is-read-only error should be related some configs adjustments. Eventhough, i'm not trying to write anything in the database, it's weird i am seeing it.

execute_query is a wrapper function that calls cursor.execute() from psycopg2 with the parameters @adrian

Comment: What happens if you run the query in `psql` using `BEGIN read only; <query>`?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was happening because one of the mviews i use is a combination (union all) of two different mviews and for some reason, psql was throwing an error saying transaction is read only. The error message was pretty unclear to solve this.